# Grouping characters to form strings in c

Tags: c, string

I am doing a school C project. In the project , I have 48 characters hold in char holdReference[48] and every 8 of them must form 1 string. Thus, for example:

```
holdReference[0] = '0';
holdReference[1] = '0';
holdReference[2] = '0';
holdReference[3] = '0';
holdReference[4] = '1';
holdReference[5] = '2';
holdReference[6] = 'd';
holdReference[7] = '8';
....
```

Result strings formed by 8 characters hold in char HexReference[6][9] which means that HexReference holds 6 strings which have 8-bit length.

Here is my code:

```
char HexReference[6][9];


int hx = 0; 
int indexxx;
int hex = -1;

while(hx<charNumber)
{
    if(hx%8 == 0)
    {
        indexxx = 0;
        hex++;
        HexReference[hex][indexxx] = holdReference[hx];
        indexxx++;
    }
    else
    {

        HexReference[hex][indexxx] = holdReference[hx];
        indexxx++;
    }

    hx++;
}
printf("%s" , HexReference[0]); --> prints 000012d8/000017f3
```

Problem is that even if HexReference[0] must hold 000012d8 , 000012d8/000017f3 is printed on the console. 000017f3 must be hold in HexReference[1].

I will be very thankful if you help me soon.

Comment: Use a debugger to understand.

Comment: Where is the null char? '\0'

Comment: I debugged but I cannot understand what causes the problem.

Comment: Or you could do this `for (int i = 0;i < sizeof(HexReference[0]) / sizeof(HexReference[0][0]); ++i) { printf("%c", HexReference[i]); }`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to allocate enough space for the null-terminator "\0" at the end of each string.
And also since you are putting the chars one by one you also need to add the null-terminator manually.

Answer (score 0):

the reason could be you did not added '\0' after first row data end so that is why second row string is printed with that

Comment: I have changed it to char HexReference[charNumber/8][9]; but same problem still arises.

Comment: please once try this holdReference[8] = '\0';

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
char HexReference[6][10];

int hx = 0; 
int indexxx;
int hex = -1;

while(hx<charNumber)
{
if(hx%8 == 0)
{
    indexxx = 0;
    hex++;
    HexReference[hex][indexxx] = holdReference[hx];
    HexReference[hex][10] =0;
    indexxx++;
}
else
{

    HexReference[hex][indexxx] = holdReference[hx];
    indexxx++;
}

hx++;
}
printf("%s" , HexReference[0]);
```